# What does this C++ syntax means?

Tags: c++, oop, syntax

I am trying to understand the inner workings of a cpp code.
The bit I am focusing is composed of 2 .cpp / .h.
The Base class is called Ionization.
The Derived class is called IonizationTunnel.

Inside IonizationTunnel.cpp I see the following:

```
#include "IonizationTunnel.h"
IonizationTunnel::IonizationTunnel( Params &params, Species *species ) : Ionization( params, species ) {
code 
code which uses params and species
code 
}
```

I understand that it is about IonizationTunnel constructor IonizationTunnel(Params &params, Species *species) which needs to be written with its ''prefix'' IonizationTunnel:: so that it is clear it is coming from IonizationTunnel class.

I do not understand the : Ionization() end-bit. Is it a call to the Base class constructor? If so, why is it there and why isn't it written as :Ionization{params, species}?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called a member initializer list. It's the only place you can call the base constructor, there is no `super()` like in Java or Python.

Both `()` and `{}` are ok for initialization: the former performs "direct initialization", the latter performs "direct list initialization".

Their behavior can differ sometimes. E.g. `vector<int> v(1, 2)` creates a vector of a single element (2), while `vector<int> v{1, 2}` creates a vector of two elements.

`()` is more common for constructing base classes as it was there long before C++11. Its behavior is also less ambiguous before C++20: it can only call a base constructor.